# MySQL decrement user variable on value change?

Tags: mysql, case, decrement, user-defined, user-variables

I have a problem with `MySQL user defined variables`!

My table looks like this ..

```
plz    |    uid
4000        1
4000        2
9000        3
7000        4
```

Desired output ..

```
rownum  |  plz    |    uid
1000       4000         1
1000       4000         2
999        9000         3
998        7000         4
```

I want to `SELECT` a non existing column `rownum` as a flag column, along with `plz` and `uid` column. If the value in `plz` column changes, `rownum` column should be decreased by 1. All the same `plz` must have same `rownum`. `plz` is unique.

My approach ..

```
SELECT   
  (CASE WHEN @plz <> user.plz THEN @row := @row -1 ELSE @row END) AS rownum, @plz:= user.plz, uid
                                 
FROM             
  (SELECT @row := 1001) r, user
LEFT JOIN 
  geodb_locations ON user.plz = geodb_locations.id 
WHERE 
  user.plz IN(29386,30013,29271,30406)         
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(user.plz,29386,30013,29271,30406), 
  uid DESC
```

This query works, but only at second call. First call all values of `rownum` are set to 1001. How to change the `CASE WHEN statement` that it works at first call? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit QUERY**

```
SELECT   
            @prev as previous, @prev := u.plz as current, CASE WHEN @prev <> u.plz THEN @row := @row -1 ELSE @row END AS rownum,
            uid
                                 
            FROM             
                (SELECT @prev := NULL, @row := 1001) as r, user as u
            LEFT JOIN 
                geodb_locations ON u.plz = geodb_locations.id 
            WHERE 
                u.plz IN(29386,30013,29271,30406) AND
                freigeben=1 AND 
                uid != 97548          
            ORDER BY 
                FIELD(u.plz,29386,30013,29271,30406), 
                uid DESC
```

The output is correct but the CASE WHEN seems to fails!? rownum is always 1001! Even if @prev is NOT EQUAL. Any ideas? Where is my fault?

Output

```
+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| previous | current | rownum | uid   |
+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| NULL     |   29386 |   1001 | 92014 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 87223 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 83160 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 81322 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 81293 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 81259 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 34213 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 34026 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 32851 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 32668 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 32358 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 31338 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 27765 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 26254 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 23474 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 23130 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 20512 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 14864 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 | 10951 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 |  8045 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 |  6921 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 |  4459 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 |  3152 |
| 29386    |   29386 |   1001 |  1939 |
| 29386    |   30013 |   1001 | 65193 | <-- @prev <> u.plz why NO decreasing `rownum`
| 30013    |   29384 |   1001 | 12883 |
| 29384    |   29385 |   1001 | 32667 |
| 29385    |   29232 |   1001 | 86641 |
| 29232    |   29481 |   1001 | 94521 |
| 29481    |   29481 |   1001 | 33950 |
| 29481    |   29481 |   1001 | 33926 |
| 29481    |   29667 |   1001 | 16027 |
| 29667    |   29667 |   1001 |   496 |
| 29667    |   29355 |   1001 | 96013 |
+----------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Why not match the tables in the question with the query and show example data. In the query the `@plz` is uninitialized.

Comment: There is only one table .. plz is initialized in the select @plz:= user.plz ?

Comment: The two tables in the query are `geodb_locations` and `user` and the `@plz` assignment happens after it has been used in `CASE WHEN @plz <>`.

Comment: tried to initialize before CASE WHEN in the select without changes .. if i put @plz := user.plz at the beginning of the select, second call fails!

Comment: how to match the tables? how could i join the tables to get a third column rownum if the plz has changed flagged with decreasing number starting at 1000 for example? I want to group flag the plz. each row with the same plz should get unique number as rownum. the plz itself are unique and ordered